# Any difference between these comparisions

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have seen this type of conditions

```
String s="something";

if(s != null){
statements;
}
```

and

```
if(!(s==null)){
statements;
}
```

is there any differences while running the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, both statements are exactly the same.

Comment: +0: Except the second one doesn't compile. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that the second one doesn't compile. What you need is

```
if(!(s == null))
```

which is the same as

```
if(s != null)
```

Unary operators have precedence over binary operators so

```
if(!s == null)
```

is like

```
if((!s) == null)
```

which doesn't compile either.

Comment: Perhaps I'm blind - but why should his second statement not compile. Would you please explain it to me?

Comment: Unary operators have precedence over binary operators.

Comment: ic - GeekDude edited his question in the meantime and corrected the question. Didn't recognize this and so I could not find a reason why it should not compile. Sorry - your answer was clear and correct before his edit (and now is again ;) )

Answer (score 1):

They should be same as compiler is smart enough to simple optimization like these.

Answer (score 0):

First one will do "if s isn't null" (inequality check) and the second one will do "if not s is null" (equality check, negation).

In terms of functionality, it's the same. In terms of performance, it's so close that it doesn't really matter, and a sane compiler should optimise the latter to the former.

The important thing is that you maintain readability. Don't convolute your logic to attempt micro-optimisations. There is *zero benefit* in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same and generate the exact same byte code.